# How to do BigDecimal modulus comparison

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Im getting confused on how to write a simple modulus comparison if statement. I basically just want to check if x is a multiple of 20 when x is a BigDecimal.
Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
if( x.remainder(new BigDecimal(20)).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0 ) {
   // x is a multiple of 20
}
```

Answer (score 17):

You should use [remainder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#remainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) method:

```
BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(100);
BigDecimal remainder = x.remainder(new BigDecimal(20));
if (BigDecimal.ZERO.compareTo(remainder) == 0) {
    System.out.println("x can be divided by 20");
}
```